# How can parse a Excel file with multiple sheets in a for loop

Tags: excel, pandas, parsing

I want to import an Excel file in Python with 4 sheets, for every sheet I need one data frame.

I try something like this:

```
data=ExcelFile(path)
sheets=data.sheet_names

for i in range(0,4):
  df[i]=pd.read_excel(path,sheet_name=i)

sales=df[0]
customers=df[1]
dates=df[2]  
employees=df[3]
```

The las part of the code is the part that I want to automatize.

Thanks!

Comment: See the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html)  - specify multiple sheet names and get a dict of `DataFrame` as a result.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this:

```
data = pd.ExcelFile("/content/data.ods")
sales = pd.read_excel(data, 'Sheet1')
customers = pd.read_excel(data, 'Sheet2')
dates = pd.read_excel(data, 'Sheet3')
employees = pd.read_excel(data, 'Sheet4')

sales.head()
customers.head()
dates.head()
employees.head()
```

Note: "data.ods" it's file I created to try